# Multiple attacks, parry and actions

Tags: combat, rogue-trader

When fighting someone with the trait like Swift Attack/Lightning Attack (as a full action, make 2/3 attacks), does the player have to roll for each attack can he roll once for all of them?

Also, how does parry work against it? Does the other player have to make a roll for parrying each attack?

Another question, I believe the description implies it, but when carrying two melee weapons, these traits allow you to strike 2/3 times as a full action, yet it says you can also land another hit with the other weapon... but this is included within the full action you used to use the talent that allows you to attack multiple times right? Or can you just use the full action to use the talent and then your turn is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bonus from these talents are additional attacks, so they would roll separetely for each attack.

Generally, characters only get one reaction action per round, so they would only be able to parry/dodge one of the attacks.

If you have **'Two Weapon Wielder'**, the bonus granted is allowed to attack with both in the same action (but at a penalty of -20). Combined with the Swift Attack, the description says only one of the melee weapons will get the additional attacks (which are still at -20) and only gets one attack with the other.

e.g. The character is weilding a sword in both of his hands and has the '**Two Weapon Wielder'** talent as well as the '**Swift Attack**' talent.

For a full action, he chooses to use **Swift Attack**. This results in **2 attacks** from the sword in his right hand at -20 and **1 attack** from the sword in his left hand at -20

Comment: Is there any way to avoid two weapon wielding penalty, as a player?

Also, a demon NPC using both "hands" as a natural weapon would be affected by these penalties?

Comment: The hands would be claws of some sort - they dont count as individual weapons. If they had more than one pair of 'hands', you would look at the Multiple Arms trait which allows you to use multiple attacks, which again is different to two weapon wielder

Comment: But let's say the daemon has a venomous rending claw in one hand and an impact damage whip (which doesn't hurt) in the other. Would this count as two weapon, or would the daemon use multiple attacks without penalty?

Comment: I'd say that it is two weapons - not too familiar if there are any special traits for demons to handle this. Might be in one of the supplements